# Radio Buttons Not Validating

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to validate this form and am having trouble with the radio buttons. Everything else was working just fine until I added the buttons. Can someone please explain what I am missing. I do not know much about JavaScript. I am not sure if you will need more code than this, but this is the html and JavaScript for the radio part. Thanks!

```
<label class="required" for="buttons">How May I Contact You:</label><br/>
    <input id="radio" type="radio" name="contact" value="email">Email<br>
    <input id="radio" type="radio" name="contact" value="no contact">No Contact<br>
    <span id="radio_validation" class="error"></span>

var radio = document.getElementById('name');
  var radio_validation = document.getElementById("radio_validation");
if (radio.value === "") {
     valid =0;
     email_validation.innerHTML = "Field Required";
     email_validation.style.display = "block";
     emal_validation.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "#FFDFDF";
   } else {
    email_validation.style.display = "none";
    email_validation.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
  }
```

Thanks for your help everyone. This is all the code before I added the buttons and it worked great. I add the buttons and I keep getting the error that I put in the comments below all of a sudden. I never moved that file.

```
function validateForm() {
  var valid = 1;
  var email = document.getElementById('email');
  var email_validation = document.getElementById("email_validation");
  var name = document.getElementById('name');
  var name_validation = document.getElementById("name_validation");
  var message_validation = document.getElementById("message_validation");
  var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

  if (name.value === "") {
    valid = 0;
    name_validation.innerHTML = "Field Required";
    name_validation.style.display = "block";
    name_validation.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "#FFDFDF";
  } else {
    name_validation.style.display = "none";
    name_validation.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";

  }

  if (message.value === "") {
    valid = 0;
    message_validation.innerHTML = "Field Required";
    message_validation.style.display = "block";
    message_validation.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "#FFDFDF";
  } else {
    message_validation.style.display = "none";
    message_validation.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
  }

  if (email.value === "") {
    valid = 0;
    email_validation.innerHTML = "Field Required";
    email_validation.style.display = "block";
    email_validation.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "#FFDFDF";
  } else {
    email_validation.style.display = "none";
    email_validation.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
  }

  if(!filter.test(email.value)) {
    valid = 0;
    email_validation.innerHTML = "Invalid email address";
    email_validation.style.display = "block";
    email_validation.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "#FFDFDF";
  } else {
    email_validation.style.display = "none";
    email_validation.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
  }
  if (!valid)
    return false;
}


</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<header>
   <img id="headerText" src="images/headerText.png" alt="Header Text"/>
    <nav>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Explore</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="aboutUs.html">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="contactUs.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
   </nav>
   </header>
<aside>  
   <img id="contactText" src="images/contactText.png" alt="Contact Text"/> 
</aside>
<div id="contactForm">
   <form id="contact_form" action="thanks.html" method="POST" onsubmit="return validateForm();" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="row">
    <label class="required" for="name">Your name:</label><br />
    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" value="" size="30" /><br />
    <span id="name_validation" class="error"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <label class="required" for="email">Your email:</label><br />
    <input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="" size="30" /><br />
    <span id="email_validation" class="error"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <label class="required" for="message">Your message:</label><br />
    <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><br />
    <span id="message_validation" class="error"></span>
  </div>
    <label class="required" for="buttons">How May I Contact You:</label><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="contact" value="email">Email<br>
    <input type="radio" name="contact" value="no contact">No Contact<br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send email" />
</form>
```

Comment: `id` has to be unique

Comment: Can you explain that please?

Comment: An id attribute cannot have the same value as another on the page. You have two elements with the same id. This is invalid and will cause you problems when selecting

Answer (score 0):

```
if (radio.value === "")
```

to

```
if ( radio.checked  )
```

Comment: Thanks. For some reason I am getting a GET file:///E:/WGD%20242/week%207/script.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND Error, but I have this script.js in my root folder. I am not understanding this

Comment: its mean the file script.js  is not found u need to correct its path

Comment: yes, but this path worked fine until I added the button part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**script**

```
var validate = function () {
    var r0 = document.getElementById('radio0').checked;
    var r1 = document.getElementById('radio1').checked;
    var err = document.getElementById('radio_validation');
    err.className = r0 || r1 ? "error hide" : "error show";
};
```

**html**

```
<label class="required" for="buttons">How May I Contact You:</label>
<br/>
<input id="radio0" type="radio" name="contact" value="email">Email
<br>
<input id="radio1" type="radio" name="contact" value="no contact">No Contact
<br> <span id="radio_validation" class="error hide">Field Required</span>

<input type="button" onclick="validate()" value="Check" />
```

**css**

```
.error {
    color: red;
}
.show {
    visibility: visible;
}
.hide {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```